# Can an R vignette title include an image?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I would like to add my package's hex logo to the title line of its package vignette.

I am mostly clueless about CSS but I thought this could work:

````
---
title: "x"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{x}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{css}
h1::after {
   content: "";
   height: 3063px;
   width: 3550px;
   float: right;
   background-image: url("logo.png");
   background-size: contain;
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
````

It leaves a space but the logo does not show up.

Can anybody spot what I am doing wrong or does anybody have a snippet for adding a graphic to the title line of a vignette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how flexible it is about placement, but just adding a Markdown image link to the title entry worked for me.  That is, set your YAML to something like this:

```
---
title: "Vignette Title ![alt text](../man/figures/logo.png)"
```

The path to the image assumes that the image is in the package `man/figures` directory, and that the vignette is being produced in the `inst/doc` directory and installed into `doc`.

Possibly you could put the figure in `inst/doc`, and refer to it without any path specified, but I didn't try that.

Comment: Thank you.  This, plus a little CSS works beautifully in the vignette. Unfortunately, the `{pkgdown}` website includes that [text in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73339633/in-pkgdown-how-do-i-specify-article-titles-text).  So, I think I need another solution.

Comment: I'd report that as a bug on the `pkgdown` site.  They might say that including the image in the title is not supported, but then maybe they'll give a better solution!

Comment: Thanks again.  I still am wondering why I can't use a pseudo-element in my vignettes.  I have made a simpler reprex to show the problem.  I will start it as a new question and see if that gets me closer.